# Fatal error: Call to undefined function site_url() in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, redirect, http-redirect

I have a form that that has ACTION="upload.php". This file is present in the same directory as the form is in. Now what I want is to show a message when the form does the operation successfully navigate back to page that has the form. Something like this:
This is the page where I upload the file.
[image]

Then on Upload button click, it goes to 'upload.php':

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('url');
$site_path = site_url();
$targetfolder = "doc_libraray/";     
 $targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;    
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))   
{
     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    return;
}    
else {   
 echo "Problem uploading file";  
}?>
```

The problem here is when I try to use siteURL() to redirect after upload success, it gives me a fatal error message. Not able to understand why? Any suggestions on how to achieve it?

**OR**
Is there a way to process the uploaded file on the same page itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need to call a separate file to execute the upload

The code can exist in the same file, and then just execute it with something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
...code here
}
```

you can just either leave the action field in your form blank or set it to

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try change `site_url()` to `base_url()`;